# What is .first attribute of FileManager urls?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

In order to cache images downloaded from the internet to the user's iPhone I have implemented the following code:

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(info.dbName + ".png")
try data!.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
print("Saved img \(info.dbName)")
```

I'm starting to understand core data in iOS a little more now but I'm having a hard time figuring out what the `.first!` refers to in the first line above.

Can anybody please help me understand this better so I'm sure that the way I'm caching images is correct and safe?

Answer (score 0):

That function returns an Array of URLs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls

The `first!` call then gets the first element: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689165-first

As the `first` function returns an Optional, the `!` force unwraps it.

Comment: Got it, thankyou. Do you think it's safe to force unwrap it?